# Can we install a Kubernetes cluster on RHEL atomic hosts?

Tags: redhat, kubernetes, rhel7

We want to install an on premise Kubernetes cluster. We have a license for RHEL and [RHEL atomic](https://rhelblog.redhat.com/2017/03/13/introducing-the-red-hat-enterprise-linux-atomic-base-image/). I know Red Hat has its own Kubernetes based platform called OpenShift. OpenShift can be installed on Centos7/RHEL7 but I read it's the best to install it on RHEL7 Atomic because this OS is optimized for containerization.

Now we don't really want OpenShift but we prefer Kubernetes. Is it possible/supported to install Kubernetes on RHEL 7 Atomic?

Kubernetes is showing as prerequisites:

```
One or more machines running one of:

    Ubuntu 16.04+
    Debian 9
    CentOS 7
    RHEL 7
    Fedora 25/26 (best-effort)
    HypriotOS v1.0.1+
    Container Linux (tested with 1576.4.0)
```

Does RHEL7 include RHEL7 atomic?

Answer (score 0):

[RHEL Atomic Host](https://access.redhat.com/articles/2772861) is a lightweight version of `RHEL` server optimised for microservices; it also supports Kubernetes single/master node implementation. If you consider provisioning you cluster in a wide range of services, have a look at `OpenShift Container Platform` which provides multi-host orchestration.

Here is the [Link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html-single/getting_started_with_kubernetes/index)  with steps for a Kubernetes cluster implementation on RHEL Atomic Host.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Because kubernetes can run  in containers like coreos. You can take a look at [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray) project at github.com. It says that CentOS Atomic is supported. Red Hat Atomic and CentOS are the same.